Has anyone a good workaround for padEnds = false, but still viewing/selecting the last page of the PageView
In the following open GitHub issue my problem is explained
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115755
What is the best practice to have the first item align to the left, but also be able to click and scroll to the last item of my pageview?
I tried to offset the inital container around but that didn't work smoothly
SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 230,
          child: PageView.builder(
              pageSnapping: true,
              padEnds: false,
              controller: _pageController,
              itemCount: _items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  
                  onTap: () {
                    _pageController.animateToPage(
                      index,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    );
                  },
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: ItemBuilder(items: _items, index: index)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),

